# How can I create a directory in the system where my application is running?

Tags: java

How can I create a directory in the system where my application is running, At present directory created and files are generated at the server, I need it in client system.

Comment: you cant do it with server site code (java) in server-client scenario  try with javascript

Comment: You have an application running (I assume) on both the server and a client. Which are you talking about? Also, can you show us what you've tried up to this point to create the directory?

Comment: I doubt it's possible even with java script... You need something like a java applet or Java web launch to achieve this... But making it run on modern browers is such a pain because of security concerns...

Comment: @Krish Why do you want it to be done in this way ? Why cant you make a user to download a zip file from the server? Any specific reasons to go with this approach ?

Comment: You have to be more clear. You never indicated that this is a web application. Client server application are not only java server side, browser client side. For java client side my solution is correct. So the answer is correct for the level of clarity of your question. Don't add a minus.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe why you think you need this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Its web application, running over an IP address, I am trying to produce log data for the end user.

Comment: "I am trying to produce log data for the end user" this still doesn't explain why you want to create directory on users side. Why not simply generate text file and send it to user so he could download it where he wants?

Answer (score 0):

Write a client software, make user install it, let it create anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

`directory` objects can be created on the `server` only.
You need to share that directory to the `client`, using `Samba`, or whatever networking mechanism applies.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ol_about_samba.html

Answer (score -2):

If the client code is a Java application, as an example a

- Swing Application
- Java FX Application

you can simply use the `mkdir` method of class `File`

```
new File("/mydir").mkdir();
```

Check if you have the rights to do that.

Comment: will it create directory in client site in web applications.?

Comment: OP needs to create a directory on client, this will create a directory on the server where the app is hosted

Comment: If the client code is java and this lines of codes are put on the client side this creates a directory on the client side. It was explicitly indicated in the last two rows!

Comment: There is no indication that this is a web application. It was indicated only as client server application. It has been tagged as java. So it should be a java client side. If not it must be indicated.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO, My spplication a web application developed in Oracle jDeveloper.

Comment: Already used new File("/mydir").mkdir(); method to create the directory. But it creates directory in server system where my application is hosted. I need the same to be created in each individual end user's system. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance....

Comment: You can't create directories from javascript for security reasons. In addition you don't know the disk structure and operating system of the client. What you can do is create a zip file that has files and directories in the format you like on the server and return it to the client.